# Far Manager - *.cpp file association

Tags: c++, c, ide, software-update, far-manager

I've been trying to get started with Far Manager, but there are not many good resources out there for setting it up as an ide. Specifically, I'm trying to create a *.cpp file association so I can compile and send my code to the console. When I compile the code currently it just displays the location address of the compiler. For context I'm using Dev-Cpp g++ compiler.

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PCBor.png)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it means that compilation was successful? And put path to g++ to the environment variables

I can recommend these sources for setting up Far Manager as an IDE:

1. https://codeforces.com/blog/entry/532?
2. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XYsJFC41D4o (first minutes)